# How do you change the color of text in a UITextView?

Tags: iphone

How do you change the color of text in a UITextView?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
yourTextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Looking up UITextView in the documentation gives this immediately. ;-)

Comment: in XCode if you do `yourTextView.` and then press ESC then it will come up with a list of properties you can set. Its always best to have a look through this first, simple questions like this can be solved easily by just having a look first.

Comment: The answer below by @Olie provides insight as to why it doesnt work for some people.

Answer (score 16):

In the end, `setTextColor:` is the answer, there's an important detail missing from the earlier answers:  To get this to work in iOS 8, I had to set the color =after= I set the text.

Hence,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _myTextView.text   = @"yadda yadda yadda...";

    // etc., snip
```

Did **NOT** work, while

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myTextView.text   = @"yadda yadda yadda...";
    _myTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // etc., snip
```

**DID** work.  This strikes me as a bug in iOS 8, which I will write up.

Comment: (NOTE: Radar #20601113)

Comment: Is it fixed in iOS 9.0 or >?

Comment: This is fixed in iOS 10.0, so you should still do this when developing apps for any target below that.

Answer (score 6):

I spot that setting

```
_textView.selectable = true;
```

solves that strange issue.