# UIPickerView With UITextView Color?

Tags: ios7, uitextview, uipickerview

Im trying to change UITextView "text color" to White.  I don't care if the picker stays Black, but it would be nice to be able to change both.  (The textView is displaying what the UIPickerView has selected.) I'm using StoryBoards.

I'm Very New.   Here's my .M

```
`#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
//@synthesize scrolly;
@synthesize Picker, PickerData;


-(void) setTorchOn:(BOOL)isOn
{
    AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:isOn ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}

-(IBAction)changedState:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *switchValue = (UISwitch*)sender;
    [self setTorchOn:[switchValue isOn]];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  // [scrolly setScrollEnabled:YES];
 //  [scrolly setContentSize:CGSizeMake (1, 500) ];

   // [tview setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  //tview.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  //tview.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];

  NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Lav",@"Kitchen Sink",@"Dish Washer",@"Hose Bib",@"Water Closet",@"Soaker Tub",@"Tub Shower",@"Shower",@"Clothes Washer",@"Copper",@"Pex",@"PVC / ABS",@"Cast Iron",@"Hot Water Tanks",nil];
    self.PickerData = array;

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma  mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [PickerData count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [self.PickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{


    int select = row;
    if (select == 0){
        tview.text = @"One selected";
    }
    else
        if (select == 1) {
            tview.text = @"Two selected";

        }
        else
            if (select == 2) {
                tview.text = @"three selected";
            }
            else
                if (select == 3) {
                    tview.text = @"four selected";
                }
                else
                    if (select == 4) {
                        tview.text = @"four selected";
                    }
                    else
                        if (select == 5) {
                            tview.text = @"four selected";
                        }
                        else
                            if (select == 6) {
                                tview.text = @"four selected";
                            }
                            else
                                if (select == 7) {
                                    tview.text = @"four selected";
                                }
                                else
                                    if (select == 8) {
                                        tview.text = @"four selected";
                                    }
                                    else
                                        if (select == 9) {
                                            tview.text = @"four selected";
                                        }
                                        else
                                            if (select == 10) {
                                                tview.text = @"four selected";
                                            }
                                            else
                                                if (select == 11) {
                                                   tview.text = @"four selected";
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    if (select == 12) {
                                                        tview.text = @"four selected";
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                        if (select == 13) {
                                                           tview.text = @"four selected";
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                            if (select == 14) {
                                                                tview.text = @"four selected";
                                                            }

}


@end
`
```

Comment: What's your real issue? `[tvView setTextColor:yourColor]` doesn't work? Please, also remove useless code (like the iAd Banner, the setTorch). I think a `switch case` would be better and more understandable than the lot of `else if`.

Comment: You solved it indirectly.[tvView setTextColor:yourColor] no this doesn't work.  I found this question , not sure why i didn't find it earlier.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932014/changing-the-color-of-text-in-uitextview]  Like i said I'm new.  Whats wrong with the iAd and setTourch?

Comment: Your iAd code & setTorch, is irrelevant with your textview color issue. That's all.